# Is there a way to force a message on `git commit` indipendently by prepare-commit-msg?

Tags: git, exception, commit, githooks

I've a regex on my `prepare-commit-msg` git hook that works like a charm!

But when there are some rare occasions where I would like to force specific commit messages, so I would like to overrule this hook.

Is there a way?

I know the flag `-n` and `--no-verify` have no effect on this hook? Am I looking for something impossible?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you add a flag to the hook?

Comment: Can't you use `commit-msg` hook instead?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I tried my commit with the `-n` and `--no-verify` but they apparently do not work with `prepare-commit-msg` hook

Comment: Since you can't directly pass arguments to git hooks you'll have to do something else.  For instance the git hooks framework I maintain uses `SKIP=... git commit ...` to indicate that it should be skipped, perhaps you could use the same pattern to signal to your `prepare-commit-msg` hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solutions is to pass a configuration parameter to `git commit` when you want to skip `prepare-commit-msg` or other hooks that would be invoked by `git commit`.

In the hook:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ "$(git config --get my.skip)" = yes ]];then
    echo skip prepare-commit-msg
    exit 0
else
    echo prepare-commit-msg
    # do something
fi
```

In the command,

```
git -c my.skip=yes commit
```

Compared with `-n` or `--no-verify`, a configuration parameter can diable specific hooks more flexibly. You can pass multiple configuration parameters if necessary.